# How to create shortcut with icon on desktop using Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, icons, shortcut

I wanted to create shortcut on desktop with icon using batch file like this:

```
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\theiboosts1.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Internetovy Booster.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "c:\Booster\booster.bat" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5

start wscript.exe "%SCRIPT%"

"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 10
echo Const DESKTOP = &H10&>>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DESKTOP) >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Internetovy Booster.lnk") >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo objShortcut.SetIconLocation "C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll",-16752 >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
echo objShortcut.Save >>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"

"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5

start wscript.exe "%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"

"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 5
```

But it wrote an Error:

[Syntex of the command is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyPHd.png)

but there is no command between

```
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 10
```

and

```
echo Const DESKTOP = &H10&>>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
```

When i create .vbs file it is working correctly

```
Const DESKTOP = &H10&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DESKTOP)

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Internetovy Booster.lnk")
Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink

objShortcut.SetIconLocation "C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll",-16752
objShortcut.Save
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) is a special character in batch files/the Windows command shell. It signifies that a the current command has ended and a new command is starting.

```
echo Const DESKTOP = &H10&>>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
```

Is actually interpreted by the script as:

```
echo Const DESKTOP =
H10
>>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
```

Which is incorrect as you just want to print a `&` char. The "syntax incorrect" error is actually in regards to the script trying to execute `H10` as a command (which doesn't exist).

To print a `&` char in a string, you just need to escape it using the batch escape char - a carat `^`.

```
echo Const DESKTOP = ^&H10^&>>"%TEMP%\testboost.vbs"
```

Comment: Thx Jason! I forgot i must write ^ before special character. :D